# Deploy Printers To Non-Admin User Through GPO

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, printing, drivers

Trying to deploy printers to Windows 7 x64 computers for NON-ADMIN users. Server is a 2008R2 running Print Management. 3 Printers are HP LaserJets installed on the print server.

I have used Print Management and used "Deploy With Group Policy" and the printers are deploying when I login as an admin. When I login as a user they are not there.

I have checked the following policy settings:

```
Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Printers Point and Print Restrictions
User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Printers\Point and Print Restrictions
Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\System\Driver Installation\Allow non-administrators to install drivers for these devices setup classes
```

Under USER RIGHTS ASSIGNMENT only Adminstrators can load and unload drivers.

I have applied these settings to the computers and still no printers for non-admins.

I have also tried most fixes on this search: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=deploy%20printers%20gpo%20non%20admins&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&safe=active)

Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong? Group policy should be applying the printer to computers for NON-ADMIN users on login to the computer.

Comment: Do you have the drivers pre-installed? Are you deploying as a computer or user level option in a GPO.

Comment: @NickYoung I have the drivers installed on the printer server. Basic print drivers. I tried deploying on the computer and the user level. Still nothing. Only installed when an admin is logged in. When log off of admin and back in a user the printers do not install.